# 301 Redirect Preventing CORS OPTIONS Request on Openshift

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cors, openshift

I'm writing a RESTful api with Laravel 4 that will be used by a Backbone.js app.

When I deploy my code using GIT, I receive a message saying:

> Application directory "public/" selected as DocumentRoot

When using the Backbone.js app, PUT, GET and DELETE requests are handled appropriately, but the preflight request (OPTIONS) fails because of the redirect when I try to make a POST request:

> **Request Method:** OPTIONS
>   **Status Code:** 301 Moved Permanently

With this error on the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://MY-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com/projetos/`. The request was redirected to `'http://MY-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com/projetos'`, which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

This happens because of the CORS Policy:

> **If the response has an HTTP status code of 301, 302, 303, 307, or 308**
>   Apply the cache and network error steps.

How can I overcome this problem? Is there a way to bypass or configure the Openshift redirect?

**>>>EDIT**

I am getting this error on the Chrome javascript console, because my Backbone App is in development fase still. Here the steps to replicate the problem:

I have a global namespace "App", and my project is organized in this form: App.Models, App.Collections, etc.

**The Model**

```
App.Models.Projeto = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults : {
        codigo      : '',
        titulo      : '',
        url         : '',
        status      : ''
    }

});
```

**The Collection**

```
App.Collections.Projetos = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : App.Models.Projeto,

    url : 'http://MY-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com/projetos'

});
```

**On the Console**

```
var projetos = new App.Collections.Projetos;

projetos.create({
    titulo : "blablabla",
    codigo : "12jk4h3",
    url    : "example.com",
    status : 0
});
```

I am able to fetch, edit and delete models in the collection. The only thing I cannot do is to create a new one.

One last thing, the URL I'm redirected to is the same URL, but without a "/" at the end.

So even if the "url" property in the collection is set to `http://MY-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com/projetos` it seems like Backbone adds a "/", and then in the server, it gets redirected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for taking the time to write a well-formatted question! However, can we see the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Can you grab the URL the response is trying to redirect you to, and send the request directly to that? The URL can be found in the `Location` response header.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your quick reply!

I have added the details you asked for, hope I'm making myself clear, sorry for any english mistakes, it's not my primary language.